# QVBoxLayout same size with different widgets

Tags: c++, qt

I have a QVBoxLayout in my app that will show three buttons

```
-----
[]
[]
[]
-----
```

Everything is clear. But now I need to add a second QVBoxLayout (Grid is not possible) that just contain 2 Buttons. But I want to have the same size.

```
-----
[]
[]

-----
```

But it is not possible for me to bring the second QVBoxLayout the way that the buttons are in the line.

```
----- -----
[]    []
[]    []
[]
----- -----
```

Any idea how to solve this with 2 QVBoxLayouts? A tryout with a spaceritem will add too much space at the last row.

Comment: Why grid is not possible?

Comment: What about using `QBoxLayout::addStretch()`?

Comment: In case of the whole UI design, a grid is not possible.

Comment: @vahancho addStretch will add an SpacerItem. In my description this will not solve the problem.

Comment: What about `QHBoxLayout` as container?
QHBoxLayout::addLayout(verticalLayout1); QHBoxLayout::addLayout(verticalLayout2);

Answer (score 0):

You shuold add an empty QWidget or a SpacerItem on the second layout and then use setStretch(), not addStretch(), on both layouts.

For both layout call:

```
    layout->setStretch(0,1);
    layout->setStretch(1,1);
    layout->setStretch(2,1);
```